# Reaching the members of subclass from super class

Tags: objective-c, ios, oop

[sorry for my weak english]

I have got superclass and it's subclass (subclasses) - subclass is the view with some 
sprites - superclass has some helper functions for example function to fire an animation.

I want to call 'fire the animation' in super from subclass but it shows that in superclass.
I need an access the subclass view (to add animated viewsprite to self.view in subclass)

How can I reach the subclass members from superclass ??? :-/

Answer (score 1):

```
@interface MONBase : NSObject
// example action. required override
- (void)performSomeAction;
// example accessor. required override
- (MONThing *)thing;
@end

@implementation MONBase

- (void)performSomeAction
{
    assert(0 && "required override");
}

- (MONThing *)thing
{
    assert(0 && "required override");
    return nil;
}

- (void)example
{
    MONThing * thing = [self thing];
    [self configureThing:thing];
    [self performSomeAction];
}

@end

@interface MONSubclass : MONBase
@end

@implementation MONSubclass

- (void)performSomeAction
{
    [self doStuff];
}

- (MONThing *)thing
{
    return self.something;
}

@end
```